# elasticsearch and Kibana count data is different

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I found the data show in kibana and elasticsearch is different. For `example,2016-08-14 00:00:00 to 2016-08-15 00:00:00`, the kibana discover pages shows hits `6,483,898`. But when I used elasticsearch

```
curl -XGET 'http://192.168.101.120:9200/logstash-2016.08.14/myselftype/_count' -d '{
    "filter":{
        "range":{"@timestamp":{"from":"2016-08-14","to":"2016-08-15"}}
    }
}'
```

the result is `6511925`. Why is the count different?

Answer (score 0):

The query you're executing is probably not the same as the one Kibana is running. It's likely the timestamps are a bit off.

Kibana uses very precise timestamps, e.g.:

```
"range": {
  "pickup_datetime": {
    "gte": 1415684771715,
    "lte": 1415754058884,
    "format": "epoch_millis"
  }
}
```

You can see which query exactly Kibana is running by clicking the little button below the histogram in the Discover tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I select 2016-08-14 00:00:00:000 to 2016-08-14 12:00:00:00:000 .The Kibana pages show request is  gte:1471104000000 lte:1471147200000 and the result count is 54,928,237.But when i copyed the request to elasticsearch ,the result is 17528922.